# Playing music through skype with a USB headset

Tags: windows, skype, music, audio-streaming, usb-headset

I want to be able to play music through skype and listen to it at the same time, aswell as talk and hear others but i dont want any echo as i tried a process bu it ended up with everyone hearing an echo. I also want the music to be streamed from FIrefox if that is possible as i hate Winamp

Thanks

~Torhic

Answer (score 0):

I would give this project a try [Skype Player](http://sourceforge.net/projects/skypeplayer/). It works but seems have the same problem (at least for me) that stereo mix would give, so here is a work around if that happens to you.  I would first try it stand-alone though.

You will need.

1. 2x skype accounts and the ability to run them simultaneously [see this link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa829/how-can-i-run-two-skype-accounts-on-the-same-computer)
2. The **first skype client** will be used as your jukebox

   - you must **allow skype play access**
   - set the **audio input** -> **a dummy input**; *for example you could just stick a jack extender into an unused analog mic port or line in*.
   - set the **audio output** -> **a dummy output**; *for example I use my Digital Out as my main output, but have nothing connected to my Stereo Analog Output and so I selected that.*
3. The **second skype client** is what your going to use to listen and talk

   - you must **deny skype play access**
   - set your **audio input** -> **headset microphone**
   - set your **audio out** -> **headset speakers**.
4. Open skype play and set balance all the way to Playback.
5. Under **playback devices** make sure that your **dummy input is selected** as the **default communication device** as well as the **default device** *(otherwise skype play might echo)*

[image: Example of the setup]

To the left is My actual account id be talking with and to the right is the one that is streaming music.

EDIT: Oh I see you want it to be streamed from firefox.  In that case you would *set a dummy output device (analog out for example)* as your *main output device in the playback preferences* and a *dummy input device* as the *main input device*. In your *music skype client* you would *set the input device as stereo mix* and the *output as the your headphones* make sure to *turn it down to zero though and/or mute that skype client in the sound mixer* along with any other sounds you don't want to be streamed.  Keep the second client the same as described.  You wont need Skype Play.